# Jquery checkbox check / uncheck all works fine - check / uncheck one doesn't

Tags: jquery

having an issue here, I need to manually check / uncheck one checkbox.
using this code it doesn't work

```
$('input:checkbox').live('click', function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  if($(this).attr('checked') == false) { 
    $(this).attr('checked', true); 
  } else { 
    $(this).attr('checked', false); 
  } 
  return false; 
});
```

but using almost the same to check / uncheck all checkboxes work fine...

```
$(".todos").live('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.each($('input[type="checkbox"]'), function(i) {
    if($(this).hasClass('in_'+que_caixa)) {
        if($(this).attr('checked') == false) {
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        }               }
});
```

});

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing that? The browser already does this.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` is the key. Your first code snippet should work if you add that line (but @SLaks is right: the checkbox control already implements the behavior you're looking for).

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false because after you do your check, it still continues through the event

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').live('click', function(event) {
  if($(this).attr('checked') == false) {
    $(this).attr('checked',"checked");
  } else {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
  }   
  return false;
});
```

and like the comment above the browser already does this so why do you have to bind it?

and on another note, you can actually just do this as a selector:

```
$("input:checkbox")
```

Comment: I need this because I'm dinamically creating checkboxes within an accordion. when I click in the checkbox the acordion opens, but the checkbox doesn't get selected...

Comment: this is an mobile application, i don't have it online to show, sorry. Changed the code to this 'code'$('input:checkbox').live('click', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 if($(this).attr('checked') == false) {
  $(this).attr('checked', true);
 } else {
  $(this).attr('checked', false);
 }
 return false;
});'code'

Answer (score 0):

The browser already toggles the checkbox for you.
Your code toggles it a second time, so nothing happens.